# Deploy VM on Azure using created (generalized/sysprep'ed) snapshot stored on Blob

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-disk

I need someone more experienced with VM's on Azure. I have prepared image with Win2016 Server and few additional configurations. I have done sysprep and created image and snapshot after that. When I create a new machine using this image, machine fails and don't event start. So I have found another solution: snapshot taken from this machine and transferred to blob. A new machine after below code execution starts but i am not able to connect RDP...

error: VM deployed with error: New-AzureRmVM : Long running operation failed with status 'Failed'

```
$resourceGroupName="<resource-group>"
$subscriptionId = "<subs>"
$tenantId = "<tenant>"
$location = "West Europe"

# sign in
Write-Host "Logging in...";
Login-AzureRmAccount -TenantID $tenantID;

# select subscription
Write-Host "Selecting subscription '$subscriptionId'";
Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionID $subscriptionId;


# Create a Resource Group 
New-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $resourceGroupName -Location $location


#Prepare the VM parameters 
$rgName = $resourceGroupName
# Get the Azure location and storage account names
$locName=(Get-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $rgName).Location

$exSubnet=New-AzureRMVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name EX2016Subnet -AddressPrefix 10.0.0.0/24
New-AzureRMVirtualNetwork -Name EX2016Vnet -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Location $locName -AddressPrefix 10.0.0.0/16 -Subnet $exSubnet -DNSServer 10.0.0.5
$rule1 = New-AzureRMNetworkSecurityRuleConfig -Name "RDPTraffic" -Description "Allow RDP to all VMs on the subnet" -Access Allow -Protocol Tcp -Direction Inbound -Priority 100 -SourceAddressPrefix Internet -SourcePortRange * -DestinationAddressPrefix * -DestinationPortRange 3389
$rule2 = New-AzureRMNetworkSecurityRuleConfig -Name "ExchangeSecureWebTraffic" -Description "Allow HTTPS to the Exchange server" -Access Allow -Protocol Tcp -Direction Inbound -Priority 101 -SourceAddressPrefix Internet -SourcePortRange * -DestinationAddressPrefix "10.0.0.5/32" -DestinationPortRange 443
$rule3 = New-AzureRMNetworkSecurityRuleConfig -Name "ExchangeSecurePortExternal" -Description "Allow access port 25 to the Exchange server" -Access Allow -Protocol Tcp -Direction Inbound -Priority 102 -SourceAddressPrefix Internet -SourcePortRange * -DestinationAddressPrefix "10.0.0.5/32" -DestinationPortRange 25
New-AzureRMNetworkSecurityGroup -Name EX2016Subnet -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Location $locName -SecurityRules $rule1, $rule2,$rule3
$vnet=Get-AzureRMVirtualNetwork -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Name EX2016Vnet
$nsg=Get-AzureRMNetworkSecurityGroup -Name EX2016Subnet -ResourceGroupName $rgName
Set-AzureRMVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -VirtualNetwork $vnet -Name EX2016Subnet -AddressPrefix "10.0.0.0/24" -NetworkSecurityGroup $nsg

# Specify the virtual machine name and size
$vmName="exVM"
$vmSize="Standard_D3_v2"
$vnet=Get-AzureRMVirtualNetwork -Name "EX2016Vnet" -ResourceGroupName $rgName
$vm=New-AzureRMVMConfig -VMName $vmName -VMSize $vmSize

# Create the NIC for the virtual machine
$nicName=$vmName + "-NIC"
$pipName=$vmName + "-PublicIP"
$pip=New-AzureRMPublicIpAddress -Name $pipName -ResourceGroupName $rgName -DomainNameLabel $vmDNSName -Location $locName -AllocationMethod Dynamic
$nic=New-AzureRMNetworkInterface -Name $nicName -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Location $locName -SubnetId $vnet.Subnets[0].Id -PublicIpAddressId $pip.Id -PrivateIpAddress "10.0.0.5"

# Specify the image and local administrator account, and then add the NIC
$cred=Get-Credential -Message "Type the name and password of the local administrator account for exVM."


$osDiskName = "VM01-OSDisk"
$osDiskUri = "https://xxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/images/Image.vhd"

$storageAccountType = "StandardLRS"
$vm=Add-AzureRMVMNetworkInterface -VM $vm -Id $nic.Id

$osDisk = New-AzureRmDisk -DiskName $osDiskName -Disk (New-AzureRmDiskConfig -AccountType $storageAccountType -Location $location -CreateOption Import -SourceUri $osDiskUri) -ResourceGroupName $rgName
$vm = Set-AzureRmVMOSDisk -VM $vm -ManagedDiskId $osDisk.Id -StorageAccountType $storageAccountType -DiskSizeInGB 128 -CreateOption Attach -Windows

$vm = Set-AzureRmVMBootDiagnostics -VM $vm -disable
#Create the new VM
New-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Location $location -VM $vm
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the blob to create a snapshot and use the snapshot to create a new VM, you could check this [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/scripts/virtual-machines-windows-powershell-sample-create-vm-from-snapshot).

```
$snapshot = Get-AzureRmSnapshot -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -SnapshotName $snapshotName 

$diskConfig = New-AzureRmDiskConfig -AccountType $storageType -Location $snapshot.Location -SourceResourceId $snapshot.Id -CreateOption Copy

$disk = New-AzureRmDisk -Disk $diskConfig -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -DiskName $osDiskName

#Initialize virtual machine configuration
$VirtualMachine = New-AzureRmVMConfig -VMName $virtualMachineName -VMSize $virtualMachineSize

#Use the Managed Disk Resource Id to attach it to the virtual machine. Please change the OS type to linux if OS disk has linux OS
$VirtualMachine = Set-AzureRmVMOSDisk -VM $VirtualMachine -ManagedDiskId $disk.Id -CreateOption Attach -Linux

#Create a public IP for the VM  
$publicIp = New-AzureRmPublicIpAddress -Name ($VirtualMachineName.ToLower()+'_ip') -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Location $snapshot.Location -AllocationMethod Dynamic

#Get the virtual network where virtual machine will be hosted
$vnet = Get-AzureRmVirtualNetwork -Name $virtualNetworkName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName

# Create NIC in the first subnet of the virtual network 
$nic = New-AzureRmNetworkInterface -Name ($VirtualMachineName.ToLower()+'_nic') -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Location $snapshot.Location -SubnetId $vnet.Subnets[0].Id -PublicIpAddressId $publicIp.Id

$VirtualMachine = Add-AzureRmVMNetworkInterface -VM $VirtualMachine -Id $nic.Id

#Create the virtual machine with Managed Disk
New-AzureRmVM -VM $VirtualMachine -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Location $snapshot.Location
```

You also could check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/create-vm-specialized#option-2-upload-a-specialized-vhd) to create snapshot from a blob.

Comment: HI, thanks for help, I think I have this almost done, i found a lot of sources and created combined solution :) one issue which I have right now is that after VM creation from snapshot, machine starts like it was closed not properly. Appears window like: http://toastytech.com/guis/srv2k3login2.jpg
And because of that (probably) I am not able to run Custom Script from Azure...

Comment: Do you use Server 2003 on Azure?  Do you get Custom Script Extension log on VM.

Comment: If you want to use Custom Script Extension, you should install Azure VM agent on the VM.

Comment: If my answer helps, maybe you could accept it as an answer. Thanks.